# Is Gravity Cumulative

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, gravitational-waves, planets, solar-system

This is to tie in with a previous question >[The Sun's Orbit - Is it What We Think?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/400341/the-suns-orbit-is-it-what-we-think?noredirect=1#comment897800_400341)

Are gravitational waves cumulative? and if so how does this affect our galaxy and other astronomical bodies? Now I go to 'The Visualisation of Space-time Warping' Video, and imagine that the more 'Weight/Planets' the higher the gravitational force, Right?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTY1Kje0yLg

For example:

- Is the gravitational 'pull' of our solar system greater than that of
  our star alone?

For instance, would a wondering planet be more likely to come into our solar system rather than, a lone star of equal size and gravitational proportions to ours?

Or

Does the increase of gravitational waves in the area somehow reduce the gravitational effect on a passing body?

Comment: Define cumulative.

Comment: The more planets - The more gravity.

Comment: Would a larger solar system have a greater gravitational attractiveness

Comment: This seems confused. Gravity and gravitational waves are different things.

Comment: Regarding only gravity but not gravitational waves: In Newtonian gravity there exists principle of superposition, that is, all the forces from different sources should be added. But now, force is a vector quantity and while adding, their direction also matters. If a body is pulled gravitationally from opposite directions the net force of attraction can be zero in between. More sources don't automatically mean more attraction, one has to take care of the directions of attraction also. The quantity that is added seamlessly is the gravitational potential energy.

Comment: Ok, that has answered a lot !! 

Enlighten me ... whats the difference then

Comment: You seem to think that the gravitational force is transmitted by gravitational waves. That's not correct. The gravitational "force" at a given point in space is due to the current spacetime curvature at that point. Gravitational waves transmit *changes* in the spacetime curvature.

Comment: BTW, the Sun has over 99.8% of the mass of the solar system. Jupiter, at roughly 0.0009 solar masses, has the majority of the remaining mass.

Answer (score 3):

Classical gravity can be treated as a vector field. It adds in a "vectorial" way.

Gravitational potential is a scalar and can just be summed from multiple sources.The gravitational field is (minus) the gradient of the gravitational potential.

Gravitational waves are something completely different.

Comment: Yes, I've been told :/ sorry for the confusion. 
more research is required (for me to fully understand i think :) )